# Why the code can't return right value?

Tags: c++

Just begin to learn C++, and the code below can't return the right value. I can't find out where is wrong, need some help here, thank you!

```
const int CM2M = 100;
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int CM;
    float M = CM / CM2M + (CM % CM2M) * 0.01f;
    cout << "Enter the height in CM: ";
    cin >> CM;
    cout << "Your in M is " << M << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, and for education's sake. If you want to emulate declarative programming in C++, to define the relationship between variables and "get the updated value" afterwards, you can get by with a lambda.

```
const int CM2M = 100;
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int CM;
    auto M = [&] { return 1.0f * CM / CM2M + (CM % CM2M) * 0.01f; };
    cout << "Enter the height in CM: ";
    cin >> CM;
    cout << "Your in M is " << M() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's cheating really, since `M()` invokes the lambda, thus making sure the arithmetic is done after the value is known. Writing the operations in the correct sequence is far clearer. C++ also allows you to declare variables right at the first point of use, so you don't need to declare all your variables ahead of time, you can execute code before the declaration is needed. So you'd do something like this:

```
const int CM2M = 100;
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int CM;
    cout << "Enter the height in CM: ";
    cin >> CM;

    float M = 1.0f * CM / CM2M + (CM % CM2M) * 0.01f;
    cout << "Your in M is " << M << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I added the artificial `1.0f` to make sure it doesn't do integer division, which was another bug in your code.

Answer (score 3):

cin operation is when you retrieve the value:
you need to get it before any process:

```
const int CM2M = 100;
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int CM;
    cout << "Enter the height in CM: ";
    cin >> CM;
    float M = CM / CM2M + (CM % CM2M) * 0.01f;

    cout << "Your in M is " << M << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the "float M=..." line after the "cin >>CM;" line. Now you are trying to compute the number of meters before the number of centimeters is even entered, so of course the result is random.

Answer (score 0):

Because CM is only declared and used in the equation before the user has a chance to initialize it.

The current program flow is like this:

1. CM is declared
2. M is calculated using the CM value (whatever that is at this moment)
3. The user enters value for CM
4. The user sees the result of the conversion (the value for M) however it is already calculated and the user input is not actually
   used.

To fix the program move the calculation after the user input:

```
cout << "Enter the height in CM: ";
cin >> CM;
float M = CM / CM2M + (CM % CM2M) * 0.01f;
cout << "Your in M is " << M << endl;
```